# Error : NoReverseMatch at /import/group_edit/1/ Reverse for 'confirm-delete' with arguments '('',)'

Tags: python, django

```
Error : Error : NoReverseMatch at /import/group_edit/1/ Reverse for 'confirm-delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['import\\/confirm_delete\\/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

This error is from my confirm_delete.html when I want to go to group-edit.html

scenario is: going to a list template of all groups (group_list.html). For each group, you have a href to edit it. 
When I click on this, Erro appears not on edit_group.html

Hoping it is clear. Please see code...:-)

changing views parameters but not working. It seems like parameter is not sent to the def confirm_delete.

group_list.html:

```
{% block page %}

            <div class="panel-body">
             <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped col-md-3">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th>Group Name</th>
                        <th>Parent Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    {%  for group in groups %}
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row" class="col-md-3"><a href="{% url 'group-edit' group.group_id %}">{{ group.group_name|capfirst }}</a></td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{  group.groupParent_id|capfirst }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    {%  endfor %}

                </tbody>
             </table>

            </div>

{% endblock %}
```

group_edit.html:

```
{% block page %}
    <form method="POST">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 content">
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink pull-right">Save</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning pull-left"><a href="{%  url 'confirm-delete' form.group_id %}"></a>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'group-list' %}">Back to list</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

confirm_delete.html:

```
{% block page %}

    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ obj }}"?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-warning">
        <a href="group_list.html" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def group_list(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all().order_by("-group_name")

    return render(request, 'imports/group_list.html', {"groups": groups})

def group_edit(request, group_id):
    form = GroupForm(instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GroupForm(request.POST, instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Group saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
            return redirect(group_list)

    return render(request, 'imports/group_edit.html', {
        "form": form,
    })

def confirm_delete(request, group_id):
    obj = GroupForm(instance=Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id))
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Deleted')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
        return render(request, 'imports/group_list.html')

    context = {
        "obj": obj
    }
    return render(request, "imports/confirm_delete.html", context)
```

urls.py:

```
  path('group_edit/<int:group_id>/', views.group_edit, name='group-edit'),
    path('confirm_delete/<int:group_id>/', views.confirm_delete, name='confirm-delete'),
    path('group_list/', views.group_list, name='group-list'),
```

no error and going to edit page (delete is a button in this page)

Comment: try this: `{% url 'group-edit' group_id=group.group_id %}`

Comment: @katoozi `group.group_id` won't work either unless you add `group` to the dictionary in `return render(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `form` doesn't have a `group_id` attribute. You can access it via the form's instance:

```
{%  url 'confirm-delete' form.instance.group_id %}
```

Or you could include `group_id` in the template context,

```
return render(request, 'imports/group_edit.html', {
    "group_id": group_id,
    "form": form,
})
```

then you can use `group_id` in the URL tag:

```
{%  url 'confirm-delete' group_id %}
```